# How to count the same data in column A, different data in column B and different data in column C

Tags: python, pandas

How to count the same data in column A, different data in column B and different data in column C

| counties | A | B | C |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| city1 | 10 | 20 | 30 |
| city1 | 10 | 21 | 31 |

In the case of the above data, city1 is added by one

Comment: please provide a longer input (I guess more cities and cases where A differs), and importantly the **matching expected output**

Answer (score 0):

You can use value_counts() to count values in a column. And use nunique() to count unique values in a column.

```
# initialize list of lists
data = [['city1',10, 20, 30], ['city1',10, 21,31]]
# Create the pandas DataFrame
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['counties','A', 'B','C'])
# count values in column A
df.A.value_counts()
# count unique values in column B
df.B.nunique()
```